# What is bugs mean in /proc/cpuinfo on linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virus

In my /proc/cpuinfo file it says

```
bugs        : cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2
```

What does it mean ? is my computer already affected by those viruses or it is some possible bugs ?

I'm using ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Also see [What do the flags in /proc/cpuinfo mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/43539/56041) on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**Meltdown** and **Spectre**](https://meltdownattack.com/) are not viruses, they are known (hardware) exploits.

Your CPU is apparently susceptible to both of them (as are most Intel CPUs), which is what the `bugs` sections in `/proc/cpuinfo` is informing you of (as those exploits are caused by bugs in the way CPUs execute instructions)